# x86: Drive a SSD1351 OLED Display

Tags: linux, display, gpio

I've a bunch of SSD1351 OLED displays like this one:

[image]

Those are driven over a SPI Interface and I use them in the Raspberry Pi and other ARM SBCs like the NanoPi with the following libraries:

- https://github.com/rm-hull/OPi.GPIO
- https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Those ARM SBCs have integrated SPI that is exposed in Linux at `/dev/spidevX.Y`.

**Is it possible to drive this screen from a standard x86 computer?** I own a FT4232H Mini Module (GPIO/UART/SPI to USB) and also found out the AK-MCP2210 (USB to SPI Bridge) however I'm not sure they will expose the screen in `/dev/` nor if `luma-oled` can be used.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was already done using a FT232H.

https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled/issues/185